# Why can't I use rule of equality when overriding == operator?

Tags: dart

```dart
void main() => Foo() == 1;

class Foo {
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    print(super == this); // true
//     print(this == super); // Compile error
    
    return super == other;
  }
}
```

There are 2 questions.

1. Why can't I do `this == super`?
2. If you look at the return statement `return super == other`, you can tell the operator `==` is called on the `Object` class, so is the entire `==` implementation not a call which has been delegated to the `Object` class?

Let me explain the 2nd question further if it wasn't clear. Let's say I check for

```dart
Foo() == 1
```

The `==` operator defined in `Foo` class will be invoked and there all I'm doing is return `super == other` that means `Object`'s `==` operator is being invoked and the `other` is `int`, so where the `Foo` instance in above code is? Here, it is only `Object` and `int`. I think `super` is doing something else too, not sure what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You can't do `this == super` because `super` is not an expression which is explained if you try run the program (the analyzed could give a better explanation):

   ```
   bin/stackoverflow.dart:7:19: Error: Can't use 'super' as an expression.
   To delegate a constructor to a super constructor, put the super call as an initializer.
       print(this == super); // Compile error
                     ^^^^^
   ```

   Which also make sense since `super` is not an object. It is a concept we can use to specify if we want to refer to fields/methods that are overridden. But we cannot use `super` as some kind of object since our object is not multiple objects in layers where you can extract a layer and then represent this as another object. Instead, our object is a combined implementation based on how you define your class.
2. Yes, you're basically calling the `Object`'s `==` operator when you `return super == other`.

**Supplementary example:**

But remember, we are just calling the `==` operator defined in `Object`. Our object is still a combined data structure which can be illustrated by this example:

```
class A {
  final int a = 5;

  int getA() => a;
}

class B extends A {
  int get a => 10;

  int getA() {
    return super.getA();
  }
}

void main() {
  print(B().getA()); // 10
}
```

You can see that even if we call `super.getA()` we are still operating on a `B` object where we have overridden the `a` field but we are calling the `A.getA()` method.

Comment: Thank you. Almost all doubts are clear except the first question part.  As you mentioned "since super is not an object", and when we do `super == `, isn't it actually a `super.==`? -- `super` then turns out to be an object.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, what you're basically saying is on doing `super == other`, we are actually calling the `Foo`'s `==` operator, is that correct?

Comment: No, we use `super` to point to the method declared in the class we extends from (in this case `Object`). It is just a syntax since `super` is not resolved to anything (which is why you cannot use it as an expression). So in this case we are calling the `==` operator on `Object`.

Comment: So, if we're calling `==` operator on `Object`, then where `Foo` instance is referred/used/mentioned in `Foo`'s `==` operator implementation while doing `Foo() == 1`. Are we not just comparing `Object` with `int` then? My English isn't that good but I hope I'm able to make some sense to you.

Comment: @iDecode The `==` operator from `Object` is documented here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html . In short, it just checks if we are talking about the exact same object instance. In your case, you are just calling the `==` operator from `Object` which would be the same as if you did not override the `==` operator.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I wrote in my post originally that are we not just delegating the `Foo`'s `==` operator call to the Object's `==` operator when using `super == other`. Although your example code wasn't related (AFAIU). Can I edit your answer or should I write my own?

Comment: I'm not very sure if I understood 1st `super` part that good. I'm accepting the answer though, thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231029/discussion-between-julemand101-and-idecode).